# como acessar a webview dentro do metodo onBackPressed no android

Tags: javascript, java, android

Olá, estou tentando implementar o voltar para a home do meu apliativo, meu app é todo construido dentro da webview, preciso chamar a function do javascript para voltar a home, pois quando clico na setinha de voltar do android ele tava simplesmente fechando meu app, entao fiz:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

}
```

Com isso ele simplesmente não faz nada ao apertar lá, só que eu queria que fosse pra home do meu app...
Mas esse método não tem acesso a variavel do webview, alguem sabe como faço pra acessar a webview dentro desse metodo?

Comment: Ola @EcchiNya, Bem vindo ao SOpt, com o código que você adicionou fica um pouco complicado de ajudar, você precisaria adicionar por exemplo informações de onde você esta criando a `webview`, se essa variável esta como propriedade da classe, etc... [mcve] - vale apena também dar uma olhada no nosso [Tour]

Comment: Sem essas informacões não da para ajudar muito. Eu faria a webview executar um javascript para informar que o botão de back foi clicado. Algo como `mWebView.evaluateJavascript("onBackPressed()");` dentro desse evento ai

Comment: Então, Icaro Martins, eu crio ela assim setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        WebView WebView = (WebView) this.findViewById(R.id.web); Ela é criada dentro do metodo onCreate

Comment: preciso acessar essa variavel WebView  dentro do metodo onBackPressed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pelo que foi comentado sua classe esta +/- assim

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // ...
         setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 
         WebView WebView = (WebView) this.findViewById(R.id.web);
         /// ^ esta definida localmente
    // ...
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {

    }

}
```

Você pode fazer algo como mostrado abaixo, basicamente ao invés de definir a variável dentro do método `onCreate` você define ela na raiz da classe, assim ela vai ficar visível para outros métodos/funções:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    public WebView mWebView=null; /// <- definir como propriedade da classe
                                  ///    assim ela vai ficar acessível em outros métodos

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // ...
         setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 
         mWebView = (WebView) this.findViewById(R.id.web);
    //     ^ associar a webview do layout
    // ...
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {

        if( mWebView != null )
        {
             mWebView.evaluateJavascript("onBackPressed()");
        }    

    }

}
```

Comment: Obrigado, funcionou :D